# Empty array on form submit when nothing selected in jQuery Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a filter form on my page and I use multiple chosen element, so I receive array of IDs in the POST field after form submit. When I remove all items from chosen box (by click on cross) and submit my form I didn't receive empty array as field value in the POST data. So this field is simply not in the POST, but looks like must be an empty array.

How can I fix this, maybe I missed something.

Comment: That is correct thing you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by adding empty and selected by default option:

```
<option value="0" selected></option>
```

and filtering POST result on server side. For example with PHP:

```
$valuesArray = array_filter(
    $_POST['field_name'],
    function($e) {
        return (int)$e !== 0;
    }
);
```